# I'm Getting wrong calculations on discount percentage while using 10% and above. 1-9 % gets accurate answer

Tags: c#, math

I'm Getting *wrong calculations* on discount percentage while using **10%** *and above*. **1-9 %** gets *accurate answer*

```
private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTaxPer.Text))
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox6.Text))
        {
            //txtTaxAmt.Text = "";
            textBox7.Text = "";
            txtTotal.Text = "";
            return;
        }

        textBox7.Text = 
          Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotal.Text) / 
          100 * 
          Convert.ToDecimal(textBox6.Text))
         .ToString("0.00");

        txtTotal.Text = 
          (Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotal.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal (textBox7.Text))
         .ToString("0.00");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the description of your problem in the question itself, and preferably with example input, output and expected results.

Comment: What input do you have? What output do you expect? What output you are getting? Which text box is here of percentage?

Comment: Suggestion to make your life easier: Convert everything to `decimal`. Do your stuff with those numbers. When you're done, convert the results back to text. It's way easier to understand and change than repeated and nested `Convert.ToDecimal` calls.

Comment: here i give 9% in textbox6 (calculates from txtTotal)  and its displays the correct answer on textbox7. If i give 10% and above means it goes wrong answer.

Comment: What is the correct answer for `10%` ? Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Please, note that when you input, say `15` into `textBox6.Text` you acually change `txtTotal.Text` *twice*: first with `1` percent discount and then with `15`

Comment: Did you try writing this code in a Click Event of a button instead of TextChanged event? I am sure you will get right answer if you use buttonClick

Answer (score 2):

Please, note that when you put, say `15` into `textBox6.Text` you have `textBox6_TextChanged` called **twice**, 
once for `1` and then for `15`. Suppose we have `txtTotal.Text == "1000.00"`. Then we start inputting `15`: when we put `1` into `textBox6.Text`
we have `1%` from initial `1000.00`:

```
 txtTotal.Text = 990.00
```

then, when we put `5` and thus we have `15%` from previously computed `990.00`

```
 txtTotal.Text = 841.50
```

When the correct result (computing `15%` from `1000.00`) is

```
 txtTotal.Text = 850.00
```

I suggest having **two** textboxes, say `txtTotal.Text` and `txtTotalWithDiscount.Text`

```
private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (decimal.TryParse(txtTotal.Text, out decimal total) &&
      decimal.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out decimal percent)) {
    decimal discount = total / 100m * percent;

    textBox7.Text = (discount).ToString("0.00");
    txtTotalWithDiscount.Text = (total - discount).ToString("0.00");
  }
  else {
    //TODO: if txtTotal.Text or textBox6.Text is of invalid format
    // Or txtTotalWithDiscount.Text = txtTotal.Text;
    txtTotalWithDiscount.Text = "?";
  }
}
```